# How do I read/write raw hex bytes from input/output stream in BluetoothChat?

Tags: java, android, debugging, stream, hex

I'm developing an app based on the BluetoothChat sample code. I need to be able to write a byte array containing hex values to the output stream. I also need to parse through the byte array on the inputstream and read the hex values. Here's my code just to simply write hex values to the byte array

```
byte[] data = new byte [3];
data[0] = (byte) 0x53;
data[1] = (byte) 0x1C;
data[2] = (byte) 0X06;
```

However, when stepping through debug and watching "data", the debugger shows the values as data[0]=83, data[1]=28, data[2]=6. Why are all the values converted to ascii? The same thing is happening when I watch byte[] buffer when reading the inputstream.

```
 // Read from the InputStream
 bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
```

I sent a byte array containing hex values, but byte[] buffer is showing ascii values. How can I read and write the raw hex values over bluetooth? Some of the read/write streams will be short <15byte stream for commands. But I'll also need to read a large file encoded as hex bytes. Any suggestions for that input stream? Do I need to use BufferedInputStream?

Comment: I dont know if you noticed but 0x53 equals decimal 83 same as 0x1C and 28. So the debugger converts to integers.

Comment: @JonathanCruz 0x53 is an integer just as much as 83 is. The difference is the **representation** used.

Comment: @Code-Guru 0x53 is hexadecimal so if you count hex 53 == dec 83. If you would say they are both bytes i would agree but you confuse integers with bytes i think. This is not a conversion problem its just the way you read it i.o.w. which glasses do you put on to see through. Adding 0x53 to the array is the same as adding 83.

Comment: @JonathanCruz I usually used (and read) the word "integer" in the general sense to mean a whole number. I use "int" for the programming-language data type. My emphasis on the word "representation" is my way of saying "which glasses you put on". My answer attempts to explicate this theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write

```
int answer = 42;
System.out.println(answer);
```

The `int` value stored in the `answer` variable is converted to a `String` and then displayed on your monitor. The same applies to displaying the value in your IDE's debugger. **Eventually, all numerical data is converted to ASCII (or some other character encoding) in order to display it.** This is true in any programming language.

Now we might wonder how does this conversion occur. By default, the `int` value is converted to its decimal representation. This is what most humans are used to reading and expect to see. As programmers, we sometimes need to think of the hexadecimal representation of an `int` value, such as you are doing in your code. However, the computer does not automatically know this just because we set the value of a variable using a hexadecimal representation. In particular, your IDE still defaults to displaying all `int` data in its decimal representation.

Fortunately, IDE designers are programmers and realize that we sometimes need to see `int` data in a different form. You can change the setting for your debugger to display `int` data as hexadecimal. Since the steps to do this depends on your IDE, you should check the help files for details.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE. I've set the debug primitive display options to display hexidecimal values. So when watching the value of data, it actually shows data[0]=83 [0x53], data[1]=28[0x1C], data[2]=6[0x6]. The problem is that the array values are being evaluated incorrectly. My inputstream receives a byte array where the first byte is suppose to contain 0x53. When parsing through the inputstream, I'm trying to read if the first byte is 0x53. So in my code, if(buffer[i]==53) is never true.

Comment: Since 0x53 is 83 in decimal, it should be obvious that it will never equal 53 (which is a decimal number, not hex). Perhaps you need to change your if statement to `if(buffer[i]==0x53)`.

Comment: Okay, set buffer[i]==0x53 and now it seems to work. I guess I got hung up on the debugger showing decimal values and thought that's how it evaluated my byte array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The debugger *does* evaluate your byte array as decimal, by default.